# Is it true that high volume training builds vascularity?

Tags: definition

I've seen somewhere that training with really high repetitions forces the body to build new capillaries and veins, is it true?

Comment: Not sure if high volume training starts showing your veins. But regarding this acc. to the question: *forces the body to build new capillaries and veins* **No, body can't do that for sure!**

Answer (score 1):

Based on available research, it looks like a variety of exersizes promote capillary and vein growth - especially high repetition training:

https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/ajpheart.1999.276.2.h679
https://irispublishers.com/ojcr/pdf/OJCR.MS.ID.000574.pdf

Physiologically, this might be because shorter 'power' exercises don't rely as much on the vascular system, while longer 'repetition' exercises require a steady source of energy. The body adapts to what it thinks it will need in the future.